# Passing variables from jQuery/AJAX to Wordpress php function does not work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, variables

**Edit: Resolved (see my own answer)**

I have a button with the class "magic" on my wordpress page.
If I click it, I want it to call a PHP function in my plugin_xy.php to store a certain value (blub: "test123") into a text file.
Creating the text file upon button click and writing anything into it works so the chain seem to be fine but I can't pass the value of "blub" to PHP and use it there.

Here is my **jquery.main.js**:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.magic', function(e){        
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: ipAjaxVar.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'my_function',
            blub: "test123"
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        // Do something when done
        console.log("jQuery: Done!");
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is my **plugin_xy.php**:

```
wp_enqueue_script('main', plugins_url('js/jquery.main.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true);

wp_localize_script('main', 'ipAjaxVar', array(
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
));

add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');

function my_function()
{
  $log = "The value of blub is: ";

  if (isset($_REQUEST['blub'])) {
    $log .= $_REQUEST['blub'];
  }

  $filename = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/ZZZ_result.txt';
  $fh = fopen($filename, "a");
  fwrite($fh, $log);
  fclose($fh);
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to add the content of "blub" to $log so it appears in the textfile but it does not.
Any ideas?

Comment: When you click the button, what does the console XHR look like? Does it give you a 200 result?

Also is this done on the front end or the admin?

Comment: add action wp_ajax_nopriv_...... for front, if you want done on the front.
If you handle sensitive data, I would not recommend using $_REQUEST,
However Please check your data by return $_POST['blub'] and it's better sanitize it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the fix was very simple:
I changed **blub: "test123"** to **blub: 'test123'** and now it's working.